# Non-renewing subscription confusion

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

It's well documented that it's up to the developer to enable the user to use the non-renewing subscription on all devices. Whether it's done through a login/password or a code (as has been suggested on SO), why question is this: what prevents a single user from sharing these credentials with the entire world?  Or is this in conjunction with some other data (such as "restore transaction".

Thanks!

Sam

Comment: It has nothing to deal with "restore transaction"...and Plz elaborate your question...

Comment: Elaboration: Suppose the user buys the subscription for 1 year. I must let the user use the subscription on all his iOS devices. So I let the user set up an account "JohnSmith" with password "Hello". The user then shares this login and password on the Internet and no one ever has to buy another subscription. Is there a mechanism for preventing this?

Comment: Anyone? I'm not sure how to make a question be noticed on StackOverflow.

Comment: You are responsible for the expiration of subscription.....so if user buys the subscription for 1 year...than just provide a flag with account set up... set the flag true while he/she buys the subscription...and after a year make it false...and check each time whether the flag is true or false...and thats it!!!

Comment: What's to prevent the user from sharing his login/password with his friends and letting them use the subscription for free?

Comment: You can send device id along with username/password and treat them combined(username,password & deviceid) for authentication.

Comment: To prevent sharing login/password with his friends....First thing no one shares login/password with his friends or any body...and If shares  why you want to prevent this?(Dude its a functionality or you can say a common feature of most of the apps that one user should access his app on any device...and you don't need to prevent that...

Comment: And If you really want to do this than you can prevent the user from multiple login...just store some flag while authenticate the user that his/her is loggedin...and at the same time if he tries to login in another device check first the loggedin flag..if it is true than you can notify him than he has already loggin somewhere and to as a security precausions suggest him a password reset or otherwise login failure...!!

Comment: Either I am failing to explain this or you are not seeing what you are asking. Apple requires you to let the user use the subscription on all of his devices. The user should be able to be logged in more than once at a time. My question is: how do I make sure that it's the same human being and not someone he shared his app-specific otherwise-insignificant password? If there is no such mechanism, then next time I make a $.99 subscription, I will share my app-specific login/password with the 100,000 of my Bank Of America colleagues and the developer will lose nearly $70,000 in revenue.

Comment: I don't think there is any way you can track that it's the same human being and not someone he shared his app-specific credentials...you can try it with the 100,000 of your colleagues though!!!

Comment: We'll here's an example. It's a month-long subscription so I think it's OK to share. Please use responsibly. The app is TickerPicker, the login is jj and the password is jj. The feature is intraday charts. So how can the developer be protected from someone doing this?

Comment: Sorry to belabor this point, but it also implies that a competitor could sabotage my entire IAP for $.99 (by purchasing it and publishing his credentials)

Answer (score 2):

To answer your questions:

1. What prevents a single user from sharing these credentials with the entire world?
2. (In your comment) How do I make sure that it's the same human being and not someone he shared his app-specific otherwise-insignificant password?

I would suggest taking a look at Ray Wenderlich's tutorial, [In-App Purchases: Non-Renewing Subscription Tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/36270/in-app-purchases-non-renewing-subscription-tutorial).

In this tutorial, it states:

> You’re also required to make the subscription available to any device owned by the user. There are generally two feasible options you can use to accommodate this requirement:
>
> **iCloud**. Since the user’s iCloud account is exclusive to them, but shared across their devices, this is a simple and effective option. However, if your app is cross-platform, or has an companion web app, this won’t be the best choice since iCloud is restricted to iOS devices.
>
> **Backend as a service, or BaaS**. By requiring a user to create an account in order to subscribe, you can store any necessary data, such as the subscription expiry date, against their account on the server. This method will allow you to share a subscription across all platforms, simply by requiring a user to log in.

I think the iCloud approach is what you are looking for. It is not app-specific, and the user is unlikely to share their iCloud credentials with a lot of people.